# Spacing between cell of tableview?

Tags: ios, iphone, tableview

I have to set spacing between each tableview cell say of 36 pts .I am using tableview rather than custom cell for creating the cell?

Comment: so what??? any question in that???

Comment: use grouped tableview and add the contents in cell with adding section instead of rows

Comment: my question is how to add it.

Comment: add delegate function heightForHeaderInSection and return 36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table view isn't like a collection view with a complex and capable layout specification, you can't specify arbitrary layouts and spacings.

So, use a collection view, or, if you want to continue with a table view, use a custom cell and add an empty section into each cell. Set the height of your cells to an appropriate value.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by having number of sections equal to number of items to display. Each section will contain only one row. You will then return transparent header for every section which will give illusion of cell spacing.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return <Your items count>;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return cellSpacingHeight;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView * headerView = [UIView new];
    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    return headerView;
}
```